# Understanding Yocto Project sstate-cache functioning

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm newbie in Yocto Project. I'm managing several projects which all of them have a version for each: development/debug and field/industrialization. While working with the build system, I've noticed the recurrent following scenario.

1. Let's assume workspace is clean, a fresh build.
2. Launch bitbake, minimal-image with certain linux-kernel device tree and defconfig parameters. Bitbake will take some time and output files will be created.
3. Now, change parameters in previously mentioned device tree and defconfig (imagine new peripherals are added). Relaunch bitbake, output files wil be created for this new compilation.
4. Now, here comes the trick. Reset device tree and defconfig files to the setting before compiling in step 2. Relaunch bitbake and it will be nearly instant. Output files are replaced by the ones created in step 2.

So, I know this is possible due to bitbake and the use of the sstate-cache, or that's what I suppose. I've been googling around for a while but info is not too clear. How does this exactly work? Is there any kind of signature created in compilation time with the inputs of config files and stored associated to the compilation? I'm concerned about this becase I really need to trust that what I'm sending to field is precisely the correct compilation and not the unsafe development version.

And related to this, which is the difference between launching a `bitbake -c cleanall` or hard deleting deploy and sstate-cache dirs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The information is available in the official manual:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/overview-manual/overview-manual.html#shared-state-cache

Comment: Perhaps you may summarize the flow it does?